# how to make both arrays equivalent with each other in php?

Tags: php

It should be minimum number of action(moves);

Example : suppose we have 2 arrays

here both arrays as an example values.

```
$m = ['1234','3456'];
$n = ['2345','4567'];
```

step1 element of $m increment by 1(1+1,2,3,4) after that new value is = 2234

step2 element of $m increment by 1(2,2+1,3,4) after that new value is = 2334

step3 element of $m increment by 1(2,3,3+1,4) after that new value is = 2344

step4 element of $m increment by 1(2,3,4,4+1) after that new value is = 2335

total no of moves = 4

This is a way to doing it by code consider it as an example. you can use any way to make equal values.

Hope now you guys will get my point.

Comment: What will be with counting of numbers which are refer to the case `'6789'` & `'5678'`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The question is unclear. How did you get `5678` from `6789`?

Comment: Also `minimum no of moves` is equal to no. of digits present in the number if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Your logic is not clear, but I tried [like this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1910419900c616a156c0e4712a8799dc32fd4d22), can you confirm is it right ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut you have used wrong values in array use same values what i put in my question. also you can see my answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 not right..it depend the difference of array elements.consider first element of both arrays.if $m[0]<$n[0] then i will start increasing numbers from left to right by 1.

Comment: @RohitChauhan Can you please explain in more detail by editing your post?

Comment: @vivek_23 edited please check now

Comment: @RohitChauhan What will the output for `$m = ['9867']` and `$n = ['4999']` ?

Comment: @AksenP you can see answer where i mentioned both case increasing and decreasing .

Comment: @vivek_23 your case is different. we have to change our code according to that

Comment: @RohitChauhan I am just trying to clarify these things to completely understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

this will help to someone whoever is needed to break online php exams

```
 $m = ['1234','2345'];
 $n = ['2345','4567'];

 $count = count($m);
 $result = 0;
 $response =0;
  for($i=0;$i<$count; $i++){
    if($m[$i]<$n[$i]){
       $splitedm = str_split($m[$i],1);
       $splitedn = str_split($n[$i],1);
       $sCount   = strlen($m[$i]);
       for($j=0;$j<$sCount;$j++){
        for($k=$splitedm[$j]; $k<$splitedn[$j]; $k++){
            $result += $response+1;
        }
    }
  }elseif($m[$i]>$n[$i]){
    $splitedm = str_split($m[$i],1);
    $splitedn = str_split($n[$i],1);
    $sCount   = strlen($m[$i]);
    for($j=0;$j<$sCount;$j++){
        for($k=$splitedm[$j]; $k<$splitedn[$j]; $k--){
            $result += $response+1;
        }
      }

    }
 }

echo $result;
```

$m and $n having example values which i got in exam that's why i used the same.

step1 : first count no of element in array.

step2 : based on run for loop.

step3 : use if else condition to check which one is greater.

step4 : then split element value in single no (like- 1,2,3,4 for all).

step5 : now it is comparing one to one from $splitedm[$j] and $splitedn[$j]

step6 : consider every positive action as a move and storing in $result.

so that i can get minimum no of moves that can achieve the same value of $n elements.

hope you guys understand now.

This is my opinion to do that.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: who is not satisfied with given answer please comment. or if anyone have better idea to do this please share.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but it is not clear.

Comment: @NikleshRaut please run this code the you will be get better understanding

Comment: Yes I have already created alternative of this : [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e11c2812bcfc9bd20506df2b1946933aff4c921). your logic is not proper, why you need this ? why not you created separate check in instead splitting ? is it for some gambling game  with 4 path/holes ?

Comment: No @NikleshRaut you have used static value 4 but we don't know may be user can put 5 or 6 or n number of elements. please make sure with your logic. array values should be user defined

Comment: Thanks @RohitChauhan It's really good approach, worked for me.